# Sprite setTexture not working

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm new to libgdx and I don't know yet how the Sprite class works, so I run into a bit of a problem with Sprite.setTexture() not woking(I need this for animations). Long story short(as an example):

```
sprite = new Sprite (imgb); //work flawlessly

sprite2 = new Sprite ();
sprite2.setTexture (imgb); //doesn't do anything
```

Is there a problem with the way I did things or there is something else?

Original code My Player class:

```
package com.triodefender.game;

import java.util.Vector;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;


import jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Debug;

public class Player {
    SpriteBatch batch = new SpriteBatch ();
    Sprite sprite = new Sprite ();
    //Animator animator;
    float cx, cy;
    float hp;
    Texture img = new Texture ("bullet.png"), imgp = new Texture("turret.png");
    Vector<Bullet> bullets = new Vector<Bullet>();

    void Debug () {
        Sprite debug = new Sprite (new Texture("debug.png"), 0, 0, 15, 15);
        debug.setPosition (sprite.getX(), sprite.getY());
        batch.begin ();
        debug.draw (batch);
        batch.end ();

        debug.setPosition (cx, cy);
        batch.begin ();
        debug.draw (batch);
        batch.end();
    }

    Player (com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color color) {
        //animator = new Animator(a);
    //sprite = new Sprite (imgp); //this works
        sprite = new Sprite ();
        sprite.setTexture(imgp); //this doesn't work
        sprite.setOriginCenter();
        sprite.setColor(color);

        hp = 100f;
    }

    void Update (float ox, float oy, float rotation, boolean shoot) {
        cx = ox; cy = oy;

        sprite.setPosition(ox - sprite.getWidth()/2, oy - sprite.getHeight()/2);
        sprite.setRotation(-rotation);

        if (shoot) {
            AddBullet();
            //animator.lockRow(0, 1, 5);
        }

        UpdateBullets();
    }

    void AddBullet () {
        float l = sprite.getWidth()/2f;
        float sn = (float) Math.sin(Math.toRadians(-sprite.getRotation()));
        float cs = (float)Math.cos(Math.toRadians( -sprite.getRotation() ));

        float newpx = cx + (float)(l+16f)*sn;
        float newpy = cy + (float)(l+16f)*cs;


        bullets.add(new Bullet(new Sprite(img), newpx, newpy, -sprite.getRotation(), 10f, sprite.getColor()));
    }

    void UpdateBullets () {
        for (int i = 0; i < bullets.size(); i++)
            if (bullets.elementAt(i).Update() == false) {
                bullets.remove(i);
                i--;
            }
    }

    void DrawBullets () {
        for (int i = 0; i < bullets.size(); i++)
            bullets.elementAt(i).Draw();
    }

    float getRotation () {
        return sprite.getRotation();
    }

    void Draw () {
        //Debug ();
        batch.begin();
        sprite.draw(batch);
        batch.end();

        DrawBullets ();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should consult the Sprite source code:

```
/** Creates an uninitialized sprite. The sprite will need a texture region and bounds set before it can be drawn. */
public Sprite () {
    setColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
}

/** Creates a sprite with width, height, and texture region equal to the size of the texture. */
public Sprite (Texture texture) {
    this(texture, 0, 0, texture.getWidth(), texture.getHeight());
}
```

As you can see the second constructor initializes the sprite's texture and bounds (by calling another Sprite constructor). The first constructor only sets its color.
To get the first constructor up to speed with the second you need to define the texture region and bounds before drawing. You set the texture but you still need to define the bounds. Try  adding `sprite2.setBounds(0, 0, imgb.getWidth(), imgb.getHeight());`

Comment: Thanks man! I didn't know that setTexture() doesn't set bound automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I thinks you need

```
sprite.setRegion(..And select you need);
```

Comment: @Vali also you could use to avoid future problems ->Texture img = new Texture (Gdx.files.internal("bullet.png")), imgp = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("turret.png"));